# Is there something wrong with MedianFilter?

Tags: image-processing

**Note:** Wolfram Support confirmed that the behaviour of `MedianFilter` is as intended, but the description in the documentation in incorrect. M11.1 and earlier have the correct description:

> For multichannel images, `MedianFilter[image,...]` replaces each pixel by a pixel in its neighborhood that has the median total intensity, averaged over all channels.

---

**Original post:**

[`MedianFilter`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MedianFilter.html) does not give the result I expect, or the result I computed using other methods.  Is it buggy?

Example:

```
im = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Sailboat"}];

m1 = MedianFilter[im, 5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Look at the pepper-like pinkish noise at the middle of the image.  I'd expect a median filter to give a smooth result.

[image]

Let's implement median filtering through [`ImageFilter`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageFilter.html).

```
m2 = ImageFilter[Median@*Flatten, im, 5]
```

[image]

It looks much better.  I have a small personal library to access [SimpleITK](http://www.simpleitk.org/). Let's try that.

```
m3 = obj@"median"[im, 5]
```

[image]

Not only does the ITK result *look* identical to the `ImageFilter` result, it *is* identical, as confirmed with `ImageAdjust[m2-m3]`.  `m1` is quite different, even in the middle (differences near edges could be due to different padding).

What's going on? Why does `MedianFilter` give a different result than other methods of computing the same?  As far as I can tell, the neighbourhood range specification works identically for all three methods: `5` means using an 11 by 11 rectangle window.

Is there a bug?

---

**Update:** I am now convinced that this is a bug because if I manually filter each channel separately with `MedianFilter`, I get the expected result (the same as with `ImageFilter` and ITK, except around the edges).

```
ColorCombine[MedianFilter[#, 5] & /@ ColorSeparate[im]]
```

The documentation says that it *should* operate separately on each channel of multi-channel images.

> - For multichannel images and audio signals, `MedianFilter` operates separately on each channel.

But it clearly doesn't.

**Update 2:** It seems like it's not a bug after all (rather a documentation bug).  As Niki says, there are ways to compute a "colour median", e.g. [sort the neighbourhood pixels based on their luminance and pick the "middle one"](https://itk.org/ITKExamples/src/Filtering/Smoothing/MedianFilteringOfAnRGBImage/Documentation.html).  One possible direct implementation of this is

```
ImageFilter[
 With[{flat = Join @@ #}, 
   SortBy[flat, {0.299`, 0.587`, 0.114`}.# &][[Round[Length[flat]/2]]]
 ] &, 
 im, 5, Interleaving -> True
]
```

which gives a comparable but non-identical result.

Comment: I did test that this is not because `MedianFilter` is able to use integers (bytes) while the other two methods effectively work with floating point numbers.  We can test on `Image[im, "Real"]`.

Comment: `MedianFilter` operates on each channel separately, I'm unsure whether ImageFilter has the same method for doing that

Comment: @CarlLange It *should* operate on each channel separately, but it does not (I just tested that `ColorCombine[MedianFilter[#, 5] & /@ ColorSeparate[im]]` gives me the result I expected)

Comment: Ah, very good. That's a weird one! Unfortunately I hit a dead end after a bit of `PrintDefinitions`ing, no luck trying to find the specific behaviour.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This looks like a documentation bug. Apparently, `MedianFilter` doesn't process each channel separately. Instead, it applies a proper color median filter, like e.g. [the one from the IPP](https://software.intel.com/en-us/ipp-dev-reference-filtermediancolor). Example:

```
img = Image[
  Table[
   Mod[i*84 + j*83 + {0, 85, 170}, 255], {i, 16}, {j, 16}], "Byte"]
```

[image]

And the median filter results:

[image]

The per-channel median is more or less gray. But there isn't a single gray pixel in the image. `MedianFilter` always seems to choose an RGB value from the filter window, i.e.:

```
ContainsAll[Union[Flatten[ImageData[img], 1]], 
 Union[Flatten[ImageData[MedianFilter[img, 3]], 1]]]
```

> True

Comment: "the one from the IPP" link is broken. I need to look up how a colour median works. Could you perhaps provide a reference?

Comment: I found the answer (I did not know what IPP was). https://software.intel.com/en-us/ipp-dev-reference-filtermediancolor

Comment: I tried to fix the link, please edit if incorrect.  However, I have to say that the "median" concept described in that link is quite different from the usual statistical meaning.  I find it misleading that MedianFilter does this by default, especially considering that it can also operate on arrays, time series and audio, where (I assume) it uses the usual median.

Comment: This page has a more reasonable idea of how a colour median might work: https://itk.org/ITKExamples/src/Filtering/Smoothing/MedianFilteringOfAnRGBImage/Documentation.html  It simply needs a comparison operator.

Comment: @Szabolcs: The common statistical definition for the median is that it's the value that minimizes the L1 distance metric. That's exactly what the IPP median function does, isn't it? (I only skimmed it, to be honest)

Comment: But you're right, I didn't test this. It might also compare brightnesses of each pixel in the filter window, then choose the RGB value associated with the median brightness.

Comment: If I try to sort the neighbourhood based on the luminance (`GrayLevel`) then pick the median pixel, I get something visually comparable, but non-identical. However, there are usually ties in the sorting, so the result isn't fully defined. `ImageFilter[
 With[{flat = Join @@ #}, 
   SortBy[flat, {0.299, 0.587, 0.114}.# &][[Round[
      Length[flat]/2]]]] &, im, 5, Interleaving -> True]`  Thanks for the answer, now it's clear to me what *might* be happening.

Comment: The operation described in the IPP link doesn't sound anything like a median filter. The operation described in the link sounds like the output for a pixel is the color of the pixel in the neighborhood with the closest color to the original color, rather than the median of the neighborhood in any sense.

Comment: @user2357112 I suspect that the description there is simply flawed (and does not reflect what the filter does). The pixel with the closest colour is the input pixel itself, isn't it? What would make sense is to take the colour of the pixel whose average "colour-distance" from the neighbourhood is minimal, for some definition of "colour-distance".  But then I'm not experienced with image processing, so I might be wrong.

Comment: @user2357112  The description in the ITK link makes a lot more sense as a median for me. The issue with this approach is that the ordering relation that the median is based on (e.g. ordering based on luminance) would usually consider very different looking colours to be equal. Thus the filtered image may no longer look smooth, as neighbouring pixels may look entirely different, even though they are equal based on the chosen order.  This is indeed what seems to be happening here.

Comment: @Szablocs I basically came to the same solution like you above (yours is more elegant), but one should build the ceiling for the respective index: `ImageFilter[
 With[{flat = Join @@ #}, 
   SortBy[flat, {0.299, 0.587, 0.114}.# &][[Ceiling[
      Length[flat]/2]]]] &, im, 5, Interleaving -> True]` as we have an odd number of coefficients, 121 for radius 5, so we need to pick element 61. BTW, `MedianFilter` help pages says "At the edges of an image, `MedianFilter` uses smaller neighborhoods." This is the explanations why this on foot solution still differs from `MedianFilter` near the edges.